# How to do digitize signature my sms

Tags: java-me, sms, digital-signature, wma

I'm sorry for my mistake grammar and e.t.c in my question ,because English is not my first language!!

But my question:
I want digital signature sms and send it to another ,this means that digital signature to an sms and send it to another and retrieved it from other device.
This is essential.
please give me a solution for do this .
thanks anybody.

Comment: where i study about digital signature ,and how to use it ?Are there anybody for help me!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using this :-
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-extendj2me/

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5115

For Sending/Receiving the sms

Answer (score 1):

> where I study about digital signature, and how to use it?

Wikipedia looks like a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature